# Need jquery to activate a click through by clicking on a different div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was hoping someone could help...I'm new to Jquery ....all I want to achieve is a click through on a hyperlinked image but this occurs when a completely separate div on another part of the page is clicked on rather than the hyperlinked image I just mentioned.  .......the hyperlinked image needs to be invisible also.  In case anyone is wondering why I need this ....it's because I want my own custom button rather than the standard one that comes with a CMS that I'm using and it can't be changed....it's basically a work around the owners of the system suggest.

Here's what I thought would work

```
<style>

  #my-custom-button{
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 200px     
   }


  #the-standard-button{
     display : none
   }    

</style>


<div id="my-custom-button">
    <a href="#"><img src="../images/order-now.png"></a>
</div>

 <div id="the-standard-button"> 
     <?php
         proprietary PHP here that renders the standard button
     ?>
 </div>


 <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
    $(function(){
       $("#my-custom-button").click(function(){
         $("#the-standard-button").click();
       });
    });
  -->
 </script>
```

Comment: Actually what you have should work. Are you getting any errors? what's the issue?

Comment: @Huangism See my answer below.  I would be very surprised if that is not the problem.

Comment: @AndrewSteitz according to OP's code, it should work as is

Comment: @Huangism You are assuming too much.  Show me the event handler for #the-standard-button in the OP's code.  There isn't one.  I doubt the CMS that is generating the php button is generating an event handler for #the-standard-button.  See my answer and read it carefully.

Comment: @AndrewSteitz we are both assuming things, until OP actually post the generated code and click handler for standard button. The jquery to trigger the click is fine

Comment: @Huangism True, but he said that his current code does NOT work so my assumption has a higher likelihood of being correct. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The whole

```
<?php propiertary blah blah ?>
```

makes it hard to decipher but my guess is that the handler is being generated for whatever is being created by php, i.e. the php generates

```
<button id="phpButton">
    blah
</button>
```

and then a handler like

```
$("#phpButton").click(....)
```

Notice that the handler is NOT on "#the-standard-button".  So, you need make sure that you are using the correct selector when calling the click() in $("#my-custom-button").click(...)

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acsteitz/6cpPb/2).  Notice which secondary click event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question perfectly, if what you want is that when You click on one button it will act as though the other was clicked.

Here is a solution that will work IF the default button is also an anchor tag (`<a>`)

HTML:

```
<div id="newButton">
<a href="#"><img src="/theimage.jpg"/></a>
</div>

<div id="oldDiv">
<a href="whatever.com"><img src"oldImage.png"/></a>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#oldDiv").hide();
    $("#newDiv > a").click(function(){
        window.location = $("#oldDiv>a").attr("href");
    });
});
```

Comment: Although this COULD result in the expected behavior, it makes too many assumptions about the intent of the clicks.

Comment: @AndrewSteitz, Well the OP is not completely clear about his intent. The question does not explain much besides what I could understand, in a situation like this... I don't suppose we can answer without assuming a few stuff. :)